# Get nodeType of YUI 3 node

Tags: yui3

I was wondering if anybody can tell me the right way to check the node type of YUI3 node instance. ie `node.nodeType==3` for text node etc.

```
Y.one('body').nodeType; //does not work
```

Thank you

Comment: I thought, its a basic issue to find out nodeType, it is so easy to do it in JQuery, but I'm forced to use YUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found out the solution. It's a bit ugly, but... Any property of an original DOM Node (ie. nodeType,NodeValue etc.) can be retrieved by calling get method:

```
var type=Y.one("body").get('nodeType'); 
alert (type);        //1 for element(3 for text etc)
```

This is very useful for iterating over text/element nodes.
Hope this helps someone!

Comment: My bad, there's a small paragraph about this in documentation.